# Similar to for-loop in functional Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, simulation

I want to create a simulation model to learn Scala as well as functional programming (FP). I already have all the logic: creation of a population of agents (it's just a `List[Agent]`, where `Agent` is a class defining an individual member, like a particle in a gas) and some functions (moving in space, for example) that "act" on the population.

My **problem** comes when I want to apply the same functions over the initial population several times because of immutability in FP. I want to apply those functions to the initial population for N rounds (where a round is defined when all the functions have been applied). I don't know how to deal with immutable values between rounds.

Usually, I would do a for-loop where a variable changes its value, but how do you deal with this when values are immutable?

My code now looks like this:

```scala
object Main extends App {
    val soc = Society(numAgents = 1000)        // Create a Society

    val agents = soc.initSociety()             // Init the society
    val movedAgents = soc.moveAgents(agents)   // Move the agents
}
```

The method are defined such that they return a `List[Agent]`, so the type is always the same.

I've seen some solutions using `foldleft`, but I need to apply the function moveAgents to what it returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the return value of `moveAgents` with folds. If you simply want to call the `moveAgents` method `n` times, you can do this

```
val newAgents = (1 to n).foldLeft(soc.initSociety()) { (a, i) => soc.moveAgents(a) }
```

This is the equivalent of doing `soc.moveAgents(soc.moveAgents(...(soc.initSociety())))` with `n` calls to `moveAgents`

If you have multiple functions that you want to apply (with a different one each round), you can do the same thing:

```
// n/3 because there are 3 functions
val newAgents = (1 to n/3).foldLeft(soc.initSociety()) { (a, i) => f3(f2(f1(a))) }
```

If you have, say, a `List` of functions, you can try this:

```
val fs = List(f1, f2, f3)
val newAgents = (1 to (n/fs.size)).foldLeft(soc.initSociety()){ (a, i) => fs.foldLeft(a){ (ag, f) => f(ag) } }
```

Comment: Thanks! And if they are more than one function? For example, if one round is first apply `f1()`, then `f2()`, and then `f3()` (then go back to f1)?

Comment: You can just do `f3(f2(f1)))` instead

Comment: @plr you can just apply all the steps, `foldLeft` works in a very simple way. You have some initial value and a function from some intermediate state and the current value of the list and then return a new state.

Comment: @plr Updated my answer to take a List (or other collection)

Answer (score 3):

Well any simple for loop can be easily rewritten as a tal-recursion, and a *(tail)* recursion can usually be written as a `foldLeft`.

First approach, simple loop.

```
def stimulate(soc: Society, n: Int): List[Agent] = {
  var agents = soc.initSociety()
  for (i <- 0 to n) {
    agents = soc.moveAgents(agents)
  }
  agents
}
```

Second approach, recursion.
*(let's remove that var)*

```
def stimulate(soc: Society, n: Int): List[Agent] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(i: Int, agents: List[Agent]): List[Agent] =
    if (i < n) loop(i + 1, agents = soc.moveAgents(agents))
    else agents

  loop(i = 0, agents = soc.initSociety())
}
```

Third approach, fold.
*(let's remove the boilerplate from the recursion)*

```
def stimulate(soc: Society, n: Int): List[Agent] =
  (0 to n).foldLeft(soc.initSociety()) { case (agents, _) =>
    soc.moveAgents(agents)
  }
```

Comment: In practice, using `foldLeft` takes the implementation back to a `while` loop which accumulates into a `var`, but at least it is a library function not user code.

Answer (score 3):

If the intermediate values between each round is of any interest...

```
val rounds = List.iterate(agents, n)(f _ andThen g andThen h)
```